# Adding different labels to each point on a Taylor diagram

Tags: r, plot, lattice, openair

I was trying to plot Taylor diagram to compare original and bias-corrected rainfall for five rain gauge stations using '`openair`' package. The plotting is okay, but I want to label each point by their name for same for each panel.
How can I do that? Solutions will be highly appreciated. I am using the below code:

```
TaylorDiagram(kj, obs = "Gauge", mod = "value", group = c("prod","variable"), type = "station", normalise = T, pch=1)
```

And the output is:
[image]

`kj` is the dataframe I used. I can share it if needed

Sample of `kj`: by dput(head(kj))

```
structure(list(Gauge = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), station = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Sunamganj", "Sheola", "Nakuagaon", 
"Brahmanbaria", "Bhairab.Bazar"), class = c("ordered", "factor"
)), prod = c("original GSRPs", "original GSRPs", "original GSRPs", 
"original GSRPs", "original GSRPs", "original GSRPs")), .Names = c("Gauge", 
"variable", "value", "station", "prod"), row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```